# Internal Server Error when add Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods to Htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-headers

I would like to add an authorization to my web site through htaccess.

I added this code :

```
 # BEGIN Cache-Control Headers
<ifmodule mod_headers.c>
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.example.com
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Special-Request-Header
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
 Header set Access-Control-Max-Age: 240
</ifmodule>
 # END Cache-Control Headers
```

But the website give `Internal Server Error` when I try to add the line below :

```
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, POST, OPTIONS
```

A special authorization is required or it is a syntax error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with "":

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, POST, OPTIONS"
```